# How to convert HTML to PDF with working hyperlinks using docx4j?

Tags: java, html, docx4j

I used Eclipse Luna 64bit, Maven, docx4j API for PDF conversion, template letter format on which I want my HTML code. This template is saved in my database.

I want to include a hyperlink in the PDF, so my users can on click this link and open it in their browser.

This is my main class:

```
        import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStream;
        import java.io.Serializable;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.Arrays;
        import java.util.HashMap;
        import java.util.List;
        import java.util.Map;
        import java.util.Map.Entry;
        import java.util.Properties;
        import java.util.TreeMap;
        import java.util.regex.Matcher;
        import java.util.regex.Pattern;

        import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
        import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
        import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
        import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;

        import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
        import org.docx4j.Docx4J;
        import org.docx4j.XmlUtils;
        import org.docx4j.convert.in.xhtml.XHTMLImporterImpl;
        import org.docx4j.jaxb.Context;
        import org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException;
        import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage;
        import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.relationships.Namespaces;
        import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.MainDocumentPart;
        import org.docx4j.wml.Body;
        import org.docx4j.wml.BooleanDefaultTrue;
        import org.docx4j.wml.Document;
        import org.docx4j.wml.P;
        import org.docx4j.wml.PPrBase;
        import org.docx4j.wml.R;
        import org.docx4j.wml.Text;
        import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;
        import org.primefaces.model.DefaultStreamedContent;
        import org.primefaces.model.StreamedContent;
        import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;
        import org.slf4j.Logger;
        import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
public class LetterMaintenanceBean extends BaseManagedBean implements
            Serializable {
          public StreamedContent previewLetter() {
                String content = this.letter.getHtmlContent();
                 String regex = "<a href=(\"[^\"]*\")[^<]*</a>";       //Digvijay 
                  Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);      //Digvijay 
                  System.out.println("p:  "+p);
                  Matcher m = p.matcher(content);      //Digvijay 
                  System.out.println("m:  "+m);  


                  content = m.replaceAll("<strong><u><span style=\"color:#0099cc\">$1</span></u></strong>"); //Digvijay 
                  System.out.println("regex1:  "+regex);      //Digvijay 

                Map<String, String> previewExamples = this.getPreviewExamples(this.letter.getMessageTypeCode());
                for (Entry<String, String> example : previewExamples.entrySet()) {
                    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(example.getKey()) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(example.getValue())) {
                        content = content.replace(example.getKey(), example.getValue());
                        System.out.println("content after map date");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("content1:: "+content);
                if (!content.startsWith("<div>")) {
                    content = "<div>" + content + "</div>";
                }

                // Docx4j does not understand HTML codes for special characters. So replacing with Unicode values. 
                content = content.replace("&nbsp;", "&#160;");
                content = content.replace("&rsquo;", "&#8217;");
                content = content.replaceAll("</p>", "</p><br/>");
                content = content.replaceAll("\"</span>", "</span>");
                InputStream stream = null;

                try {
                    System.out.println("content:"+content);

                    if (this.letter.getHtmlContent().getBytes() != null && this.letter.getWfTemplateId() != null) {
                        stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(this.HTMLToPDF(content.getBytes(), this.letter.getWfTemplateId()));
                        } else {
                        stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(this.HTMLToPDFWithoutTemplate(content.getBytes()));
                    }
                    StreamedContent file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "application/pdf", this.letter.getLetterName() + ".pdf");
                    return file;
                } catch (LetterMaintenanceException e) {
                    this.processServiceException(e);
                    StreamedContent file = new DefaultStreamedContent(
                            new ByteArrayInputStream(
                                    "Unable to process your request. If the problem persists, please contact application support."
                                            .getBytes()), "application/pdf", "error" + ".pdf");
                    return file;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    this.processGenericException(e);
                    StreamedContent file = new DefaultStreamedContent(
                            new ByteArrayInputStream(
                                    "Unable to process your request. If the problem persists, please contact application support."
                                            .getBytes()), "application/pdf", "error" + ".pdf");
                    return file;
                }
            }
```

This is my `HTMLToPDF()` method:

```
 private byte[] HTMLToPDF(final byte[] htmlContent, final String templateId)
                throws Docx4JException, LetterMaintenanceException {
            LetterMaintenanceDelegate letterMaintenanceDelegate = new LetterMaintenanceDelegate();
            Template template = letterMaintenanceDelegate.retrieveTemplateById(templateId);
            if (template == null || template.getContent() == null) {
                throw new LetterMaintenanceException("Could not retrieve template");
            }

            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(template.getContent());
            WordprocessingMLPackage templatePackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(is);

            // Convert HTML to docx
            XHTMLImporterImpl XHTMLImporter = new XHTMLImporterImpl(templatePackage);
            XHTMLImporter.setHyperlinkStyle("Hyperlink");
            templatePackage
                    .getMainDocumentPart()
                    .getContent()
                    .addAll(XHTMLImporter.convert(new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlContent), null));

            // Add content of content docx to template
            templatePackage.getMainDocumentPart().getContent().addAll(templatePackage.getMainDocumentPart().getContent());   
            // Handle page breaks
            templatePackage = this.handlePagebreaksInDocx(templatePackage);

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Docx4J.toPDF(templatePackage, baos);

            return baos.toByteArray();
        }

    }
```

In this code I am trying to convert HTML (with `href` tag) to PDF file and in the PDF output the hyperlink must work.

The current output of this program is a PDF but there are no working links in it.

How can I activate my links?

Comment: Can we please have [mcve] instead of this huge nonsence code block?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you save the docx (your templatePackage object) and see whether that contains working hyperlinks.  Then you'll know whether your problem is in the XHTML to docx step, or the docx to PDF step, and you can improve your question accordingly.

Comment: pdf is generated but inside pdf hyperlink not working.

Comment: does the hyperlink work in the intermediate *docx*?